# How to use the webUI for Heritrix remotely

Tags: linux, remote-access, web-crawler, heritrix

Hello I have been playing with Heritrix, and would like to include it on a website/allow remote web access to it.

I have a Linux based server where I have a hosted webpage, and I have built a version of Heritrix.

The issue is I am at home now and would like to be able to offer access to the webUI in Heritrix via the hosted webpage.

I looked through the manual and discovered the -b command to bind it to remote hosts however the documentation could be better.

**So what I was hoping for was a little explanation/elaboration on how this command works and if it would be possible to bind the webUI to existing webpage**

Thanks for your time in advance

(Here is a link to the documentation im working from: https://webarchive.jira.com/wiki/display/Heritrix/HOWTO+Launch+Heritrix )

Comment: Heritrix binds by default to localhost only, which is only accessible from the machine itself.  If you want to be able to access Heritrix on a given netcard, you must provide that IP-number as an argument to -b.  Note:  `-b/` binds to all network interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `-b <public ip address>` like `-b 192.168.1.1`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a public IP, you can use SSH port forwarding to do this. When creating a PuTTY session, under Connection > SSH > Tunnels enter the following:

Source port: `8443` (or the port Heritrix is installed on, if different)
Destination: `localhost:8443` (it's good practice to match the port you're forwarding)

Back on the Session window, make sure you save the session. Now whenever you SSH onto your server you can access the Heritrix web UI by hitting https://localhost:8443